# Google App Engine only shows one Entity in the Datastore Viewer. How do I make it show all of my Entities?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, dashboard

When I go to the Google App Engine dashboard to see the data stored in my created entities, it doesn't show all of my entities.  Is there something that I need to do to view my missing entity?

As an example, here's a simplified version of my code.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class ClassOne (db.Model):
  someVar = db.StringProperty()

class ClassTwo (db.Model):
  someOtherVar = db.IntegerProperty()
```

In the datastore viewer, ClassOne is shown in the drop-down but ClassTwo is not.  Do I need to separate each model into its own file?  This is working locally, with the datastore viewer from the Launcher, in both these ways.

- Both entities are listed in the dropdown.
- I have the someOtherVar being incremented when a user clicks a button.  The number has indeed been

In production, I can't see whether users clicked such a button because the entities aren't shown in the Dashboard's Datastore Viewer.

When I try running a GQL query from the dashboard, I also get "No results in Empty namespace." as a return value.

```
SELECT * FROM ClassTwo # returns empty
```

Alternately, if this sort of behavior has its roots in some bug that isn't reported as an error or thrown as an exception, please feel free to bring that up!  I can direct my attention to debugging each component of my script instead of trying to search from some mysterious syntax or setup solution.

Comment: Aer you sure an entry is created in ClassTwo, there is no problem with your model.

Comment: I was just about to say that, this sounds exactly like what happens when you've simply not got a model of that type. Suggest turning logging on.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you create and save your models? It seems that your entities are not saved in the datastore.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this is the correct setup.  You've directed me correctly to checking on other code -- namely, where I was saving my models.  There was a typo there.  Could one of you please reply as an answer (format is correct, check other code such as where entities are saved) so that others with this problem can find this in the future?